# gcc linking object files with warning/optimization flags

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-optimization, gcc-warning, object-files

We are compiling a piece of software using generics where files are first made into object files, they are built like so:

```
arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -c -O2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -fsigned-char -I/opt/tm-sdk/include  -mlittle-endian -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-omit-frame-pointer -march=armv4 -mtune=arm9tdmi -Wall -Wextra -o src/flex.o src/flex.c
...
arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -c -O2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdeclaration-after-statement -fsigned-char -I/opt/tm-sdk/include  -mlittle-endian -Wno-trigraphs -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-omit-frame-pointer -march=armv4 -mtune=arm9tdmi -Wall -Wextra -o src/flexdb.o src/flexdb.c
```

Then they are linked with:

```
arm-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -o flex src/flex.o src/flexdb.o src/flexio.o src/flexprotocol.o src/flexsettings.o src/flexstate.o -L/opt/tm-sdk/lib -ltag  -lrt -ltmreader -lsqlite3 -lsha1
```

My questions is:
Do we need to include optimization and warning flags during linking? Would it do anything if `-Wall`, `-Wextra`, and `-O2` were included when creating the flex binary from the object files?

Edit: Clarifying meaning based on feedback.

Comment: Generics in C are compile-time expressions. Not sure why that would be relevant. And which "final stage of compilation"? the compiler runs in a single pass (from user-view)

Comment: I'm just seeing this as a two step process. Build object files then combine object files.

Comment: Build != compile!

Comment: You're right, "final stage of compilation" is confusing.

Comment: @Kyles the `-c` switch means "just compile and/or assemble, but do not link".  that last command is called *linking*. GCC will be a front end for the *GNU linker*, **ld**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do we need to include optimization and warning flags during this final stage of compilation?

Of course you don't *need* to include them for the link stage.  You already know that, because you *don't* include them.  But I think what you really want to know is ...

> Would it do anything if -Wall, -Wextra, and -O2 were included when building the flex binary from object files.

All or almost all warnings are generated during the compilation stage.  I don't off-hand know any exceptions, but it's conceivable that there are some.  Thus, it's possible that passing warning-related flags during linking would trigger warnings that otherwise you would not receive.  But that shouldn't affect the compiled binary in any way.

Optimization is different.  There are optimizations that can be performed at link time, but that might not be performed at the default optimization level.  Omitting optimization flags from the link command should not break your build, but including them may result in a binary that is faster and / or smaller.

Overall, I see no good reason to avoid passing the same warning and optimization flags during the link step that you do during the compilation steps.  If you wish, it's not harmful to pass preprocessor-specific flags (e.g. `-D`) as well, as they'll just be ignored during linking.  I presume that all this is managed by `make`, so it's not like you actually need to type out the options every time.

Comment: Correct, we are using make. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

NO You're just calling the linker with the final call to gcc and -W and -O flags are for the compiler.

Answer (score -4):

-Wall is primarily a preprocessor option, but there is also a reference for the libraries.  See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/Standard-Libraries.html#Standard-Libraries)

-Wextra appears to be strictly a c++ preprocessor option.  See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/Warning-Options.html#index-Wextra-307)

-O2 is a compiler optimization level setting.  See [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.3.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-O2-707)

So to answer your precise question, only -Wall would possibly help during your link step.  The other two would not.  You could test this by building with and without these options, seeing if any additional output is created in the case of warnings and if the code size or execution time differed between builds.

Comment: Neither -Wall nor -Wextra are preprocessor options.

Comment: I think -Wextra just has some C++ only features. I don't believe that it's C++ only. C++ only options can be seen [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html)

Comment: On the help page it says all but one is related to c++. A pointer is compared against integer zero with <, <=, >, or >=.
(C++ only) An enumerator and a non-enumerator both appear in a conditional expression.
(C++ only) Ambiguous virtual bases.
(C++ only) Subscripting an array that has been declared register.
(C++ only) Taking the address of a variable that has been declared register.
(C++ only) A base class is not initialized in a derived class's copy constructor.

Comment: @netskink in the link you provided, there are 4 warnings enabled by `-Wextra` that are C only, and an additional 10 that are for both C and C++. I think you may be misreading that list (the stuff in the code block before the bulleted list you reference are also enabled by `-Wextra`)

Comment: @netskink: From the linked page about `-Wextra": ... The option -Wextra **also** prints warning messages ..." (emphasis mine), which means "in addition to" here. You completely ignored the messages listed above. The rest of your answer is mostly wrong, too. It also does not really answer the question.